# How to generate a list with some numbers?

Tags: prolog

I want to generate a list with all the numbers `abc`, where `a = c` and `b >= a + c`.

I know how to generate the numbers, but I do not know how to add them to the list because I can not do something like `L = [Number|L]`.

I don't know how to define the `add` predicate... or should I do it in another way?
I have tried defining it as `add(Nr, L, [Nr|L]).`, but I have no idea of what to do after that.

```
c(0). c(1). c(2). c(3). c(4). c(5). c(6). c(7). c(8). c(9).
bts(L, Lr) :- c(A), A =\= 0, c(C), A =:= C, c(B), C =\=9, B >= A + C,
    Nr is A * 100 + B * 10 + C, 
    add(......).
solve(L) :- bts([], L).
```

The output should be:
`L=[121,131,141,151,161,171,181,191,242,252,262,272,282,292,363,373,383,393,484,494]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
bts(1000, []) :- !.
bts(Nr, L) :-
         N is Nr + 1, 
         bts(N, X),
         once(((number_chars(Nr, [H1, H2, H3]), number_chars(A, [H1]), number_chars(C, [H3]),
                A =:= C, number_chars(B, [H2]), B >= A + C,
                L = [Nr|X]);
               L = X)).

solve(L) :- bts(100, L).
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Here are two small tips:

1. First and most importantly, focus on what a **single solution** looks like. You can always use meta-predicates like `findall/3` and `setof/3` to collect all solutions into a *list* of solutions.
2. Second, there are more intelligent ways to describe solutions in your case. Currently, you are using *generate and test*, which is an infeasible strategy for larger problems. Instead, use your Prolog system's **constraint solvers** to declaratively describe all requirements. This lets the engine apply *pruning* to avoid generating all combinations.

In total, my recommendation is to do it similar to the following:

```
abc(Ls) :-
        Ls = [A,B,C],
        A #= C,
        A #\= 0,
        C #\= 9,
        B #>= A + C,
        Ls ins 0..9.
```

We can now try the **most general query** to see what solutions look like *in general*:

```
?- abc(Ls).
Ls = [_940, _946, _940],
_940 in 1..4,
2*_940#=<_946,
_946 in 2..9.
```

This is of course not very useful, but it at least tells us that our relation **terminates** and is **deterministic**.

This means that so-called **labeling**, which is the search for *concrete* solutions will *also* terminate. That is a very nice property, because it means that the search will always terminate, even if it may take a long time.

In this case, the search is of course trivial, and we can use for example `label/1` to enumerate solutions:

```
?- abc(Ls), label(Ls).
Ls = [1, 2, 1] ;
Ls = [1, 3, 1] ;
Ls = [1, 4, 1] ;
Ls = [1, 5, 1] ;
etc.
```

Now, to obtain the results you want, we will use `findall/3` to collect *all solutions* into a list:

```
?- abc(Ls),
   findall(N, (label(Ls),
               atomic_list_concat(Ls,A),atom_number(A,N)), Ns).
Ls = [_774, _780, _774],
Ns = [121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 242|...],
_774 in 1..4,
2*_774#=<_780,
_780 in 2..9.
```

I have also taken the liberty to apply a small transformation to each solution, so that you get the desired result immediately.

The formalism I am applying here is called **CLP(FD)**, and the exact details for invoking this mechanism differ slightly between available Prolog systems. Check your system's manual for more information, and see also [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd).

Answer (score 1):

a simple application of findall/3 and between/3

```
abc(Ns) :- findall(N, (between(1,9,A),between(1,9,B),C=A,B>=A+C,N is A * 100 + B * 10 + C), Ns).
```